# Second monitor using VGA port “Input not supported” error

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, intel-graphics

Recently I bought an HDMI to VGA adapter so that I can connect my HP laptop to my old Acer monitor. It worked fine. I have Windows 10 OS and Intel HD Graphics 5500. Everything worked fine : PC screen only, Duplicate display, Extend Display, Second screen only. All of these projection modes worked fined.

I also set the second monitor as my main display. That worked fine too.

Then I enabled the "second monitor only" setting of screen projection using WINDOWS + P so that my laptop screen is OFF and only my second monitor screen is ON. Worked nicely too.

Problem arised when I went to change the resolution (Intel Graphics control panel) of my second monitor (note: I was still in "Second monitor only" setting of screen projection). I changed it to from '1440 x 900'(which was the recommened one) to '1920 x 1080' and clicked apply. This made my second monitor go dark and only showing message "INPUT NOT SUPPORTED".

Using WINDOWS + P again I set projection setting to "Duplicate display" and "Extend display" , the second monitor works fine and the resolution is automatically set to the recommended "1440 x 900". But when I set the project mode to "Second monitor only" , the screen goes dark again only to show "Input not supported". I guess it goes back to the unsupported resolution during "Second monitor only" setting. Seems like the resolution setting is saved somewhere for the "Second monitor only " mode. How do I change the resolution back to the recommended one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With both monitors working, right click on the desktop, display settings. Select the monitor you want to forget. Under Multiple Displays on this page, select Disconnect this display.

Once disconnected, unplug the monitor from the computer and then restart. Make sure you just have one display (computer) and that it is properly set.

Then attach your monitor and let it select its own resolution.

If this fails, try removing the second display using a registry fix (caution doing this as errant registry changes can make things worse) .  Here is a Microsoft Article with the changes.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-reset-external-monitors-settings/b3a53cef-e54f-4410-b09e-6846fa297a3f

> Locate this three registry keys:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors
>       After finding them right click on each folder and select delete than yes."

Comment: Thanks John for looking into the situation. By disconnecting do you mean to choose "show display 1 only" where display 1 is my laptop display (the main display) ? Sorry but I could not find the disconnect option. I tried what you said by enabling "Show display 1 only ". Did not solve the problem.

Comment: It is possible the old monitor is too old for the setup you have. Can you try a different monitor?  Can you live with one monitor until you can test a different monitor.

Comment: Oh no it actually worked before I messed up by changing to an unsupported resolution as stated in the question. As I said it works fine when put in "duplicate display " or "extend " mode but does not work only in " show only display 2"

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a possible fix using the registry. Please be careful

Comment: wow man !! Worked like a charm . Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thank you and you are very welcome.